# Django local memory caching not working on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, caching, django-rest-framework

I have a requirement to authenticate user in my django-rest-framework application using SMS based OTP. For these I have created following API endpoint

```
GET \otp - generate and send OTP and store it in cache
POST \otp - validate OTP based on value store in cache
```

Here's my code -

```
from django.core.cache import cache

# It is used just for debugging & logging purpose
local_cache = {}

class OTPView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        serializer = ContactSerializer(data=request.query_params)
        num = serializer.validated_data.get('contact_number')
        otp = generate_otp()
        cache.set(num, otp, 300)
        local_cache[num] = otp
        print('GET Cache is : ', local_cache)
        return Response('OTP Sent')

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = OTPSerializer(data=request.data)
        num = serializer.validated_data.get('contact_number')
        otp = serializer.validated_data.get('otp')
        print('POST Cache is : ', local_cache)
        otp_in_cache = cache.get(num)
        if otp_in_cache is None:
            return Response('No OTP or prev expired')
        elif otp == otp_in_cache:
            return Response('Success')
        else:
            return Response('Incorrect OTP')
```

To persist the OTP across two requests I am using in-memory cache. It is working as expected in my local machine but not when deployed on **Heroku**. Here are the logs from heroku for reference -

```
2020-09-02T17:17:22.556785+00:00 app[web.1]: Number is 6666660008 and otp is 541609
2020-09-02T17:17:22.556798+00:00 app[web.1]: GET Cache is :  {'6666660008': '541609'}
2020-09-02T17:17:22.558975+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.69.31.173 - - [02/Sep/2020:22:47:22 +0530] "GET /account/api/otp/?contact_number=6666660008 HTTP/1.1" 200 36 "https://direct-fresh-chicken.netlify.app/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/77.0.3865.90 Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36"
2020-09-02T17:17:32.897997+00:00 app[web.1]: POST Cache is :  {}
2020-09-02T17:17:32.898035+00:00 app[web.1]: Error 400: No OTP or prev expired.
2020-09-02T17:17:32.900342+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.69.31.173 - - [02/Sep/2020:22:47:32 +0530] "POST /account/api/otp/ HTTP/1.1" 400 66 "https://direct-fresh-chicken.netlify.app/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/77.0.3865.90 Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36"
```

I understand local memory caching is not suitable for production and eventually I am planning to use better alternatives such as memcached.

I wanted to know -

- Why local memory caching not working on heroku ?
- Why `local_cache` dictionary object has empty value in post method (refer logs) ?
- Can I use [file system caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/#filesystem-caching) on heroku ? If yes what configuration shall I use ?
- Apart from using cache is there any other possible approach to validate OTP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### about local memory cache on Heroku

In general local memory cache works fine on Heroku. There is a limitation though: **both the `local_cache` dict and the Django `locmem` cache backend are local to the process and the dyno**.

So, for example, if you are using `gunicorn`, it will by default use sub-processes to handle the requests. And each subprocess will have its own `locmem` cache. The [default `WEB_CONCURRENCY` setting is at least 2, depending on the dyno size](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/618).

#### Now about the general setup question:

In general local caching can be totally fine (and extremely fast) for production use, if the process/dyno-limitation is fine for you, and the fact that you cannot clear the whole cache without restarting all your dynos.

File system caching also works, but is again only local to your dyno, which means cleaning it is only possible by restarting all your dynos.

In an environment with multiple servers / containers for one application it is actually better to have a separate cache somewhere like redis, memcached, ... which all the dynos can access.

#### cache and OTP

in general you can use the cache here to store the token. The risk in here is, depending on the actual cache backend: **if the cache is full, it will remove data**. This is normally fine for a real cache, but it would be a problem for OTP.

In your case you could [configure separate cache only for the OTP tokens](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/cache/#accessing-the-cache), which is big enough to hold all currently valid tokens.